# Ruby non-blocking libraries vs Node

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, nonblocking, eventmachine

I'm evaluating Ruby EventMachine (and similar non-blocking frameworks such as Cramp) vs Node.js.  I've worked with Node before, but have never worked with EventMachine.  One of the ideas that Ryan Dahl encourages is that the ecosystem of libraries in javascript have to be similarily non-blocking in order promote this.  This is part of the reason why Node was developed from the ground up.

My question is, can you get far in Ruby without blocking?  My assumption is that EventMachine alone is often not enough to build a complete web application stack.  If so, what other libraries in Ruby promote non-blocking IO (ie for database/filesystem/http access)?

Comment: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/Protocol-Implementations

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'll accept it as an answer if you write one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out a lot of the work of [Ilya Grigorik](http://www.igvita.com/) and his work on [Synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony) and [Goliath](http://www.igvita.com/2011/03/08/goliath-non-blocking-ruby-19-web-server/).

They help you to write asynchronous code with callbacks in an imperative style (appears to be synchronous).

Comment: after taking a huge round trip around eventmachine, I eventually arrived at Goliath.  Now I see what you meant ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @Holder Just pointed out, there's a list of non-blocking libraries to use with EventMachine here:

https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/Protocol-Implementations